# CSS fixed td size when table is 100%

Tags: html, css, html-table

If my table width is set to 100% can I make fixed td size?

This is my CSS:

```
table{
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
table-layout: fixed;
width:100%;
border:1px solid black;
}

td {
overflow: hidden;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If I don't set table widht to 100%, it is all fixed to 20px x 20px, otherwise not...

Comment: could you share the HTML?

Comment: it is just <table><tr><td bgcolor="someColor"></td></tr></table>...

Comment: Maybe its possible using cellspacing?

Comment: What about table { table-layout: fixed; }

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `dispaly: inline-block;` definition on your `td` elements, now you can specify the width and the height. ;)

For example:

```
td {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I think maybe you could add % margins or padding to parts of the table which will grow with the table controlling the td? Just trying to think where you would add it. May have to have an empty td on the outer columns and apply the above. Or make on the one stretch with screen controlling Tds with content.